# ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonpath, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to create a virtualenv with `virtualenvwrapper`, but when I use `mkvirtualenv` I get the following :

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

I assumed it was a **PYTHONPATH** problem.
But if I do a `pip show virtualenv` I get the following :

```
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: virtualenv
Version: 13.1.0
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Jannis Leidel, Carl Meyer and Brian Rosner
Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /Volumes/Data/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requires:
```

And here is my **PYTHONPATH** :

*/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:/Volumes/Data/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:~/.brew/Cellar*

It contains the directory containing virtualenv!

(i-e : **/Volumes/Data/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages** )

My **~/.zshrc** contains :

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source $HOME"/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

**EDIT :**
virtualenvwrapper.sh is written in bash, perhaps should I check my **PATH** instead of my **PYTHONPATH** ?

So, what could the problem be? How could I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Show your  .bashrc file

Comment: @AjayGupta Do you mean my ~/.zshrc? There are several things in it and won't show everything, what should the parts I'll show be related to?

Comment: Its the .bashrc file in both mac and linux, which OS are you on?

Comment: @AjayGupta I know but it is the .bashrc if I use bash, but I don't : I use zsh instead.

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61327680/8212790

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was :

**virtualenvwrapper.sh** is written in **BASH** and not in **Python**.
So **virtualenv** is called from a shell (**zsh**).
I didn't have to bother about my **PYTHONPATH**, but about my **PATH** (I was already able to import virtualenv from my python shell anyway).

I just added the correct directory to my **PATH** and everything worked fine (the directory containing the `virtualenv` executable, i-e `/Volumes/Data/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` which isn't included in my `PATH` by default despite being the directory `virtualenv` and other pip-installed tools was in).

Comment: Directory of what exactly? I am sorry I am very much exhausted. My path to virtualenv and wrapper is `/usr/local/bin`. However I installed my Pyhtton3 with HomeBrew. I don't know if messes up my shell.

Comment: @OzkanSerttas Hello, it's a bit old but if I remember correctly, it was about adding the path of the directory containing the `virtualenv` executable.
I edited my answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 66):

Re-installling virtualenv fixed my problem.

I had the same issue.

```
$ mkvirtualenv mysite
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

After a lot of time consuming efforts, 
I decided to re-install virtualenv.

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

This fixed my issues.
I already had virtualenv installed. But I think it got broken or met with some errors.

Comment: For me, I had to do `sudo apt install --reinstall virtualenv`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `sudo apt install virtualenv --upgrade` fixed it for me

Comment: Neither fixed it for me. `sudo apt install virtualenv --upgrade` gives error `ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path`

Comment: @Alex I think `--upgrade` works only if the package is already installed.

Comment: This did not fix my issue, it made things worse. This is not a good solution as the problem maybe deeper for others. People maybe mixing up their pip installs and apt installs which are different paths. The solution is to fix your path problems.

Answer (score 48):

I am using python3 with virtualenvwrapper installed on Ubuntu 18.04, using pip3 without sudo. If you are in this situation, you might find interesting my configuration.

In the end of my .bashrc I added the following rows (remember to **put your username** in the YOUR_USERNAME field):

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then restart the cli with ctrl-D ctrl-T or reload the config with `source ~/.bashrc`.
Then you should be good to go! Try the installation with:

```
lsvirtualenv
mkvirtualenv test
workon test
deactivate
rmvirtualenv test
```

If you could create and delete a virtual environment, you are ready to go.

Comment: This was the easiest solution for fixing this issue on Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem, thanks!

Comment: Worked on my Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem too. The critical part was `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/bin/virtualenv`. I searched for the `virtualenv` using Everything (a search program) and found that it exists is some long directory with `/.local/bin/virtualenv` at the end.

Comment: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` was also the line that got it working for me.  ElementaryOS 6, python 3.8.  The virtualenvwrapper installation instructions do not include this step

Comment: This should be marked as the right solution.

Answer (score 24):

1. `sudo find / -name "virtualenv"`

   Then I find the executable file path is:

   > /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
2. Touch a soft link in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory or add the path to `.bash_profile`, I prefer the former:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
   ```

Comment: This was the best option for me, since my pip installations in vagrant are located in an unsual place (`/home/vagrant/.local/bin/virtualenv`).

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is the best piece of advice I've got so far about virtualenvwrapper cannot find virtualenv. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

1. Find where is your `virtualenvwrapper` located. in my case

```
 ~/.local/bin
```

May be it's installed in

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

It totally depends on the System or Package Manager you are using.

2. Add this path in your shell configuration `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever by simply

```
PATH=$PATH:<directory_you_want_to_add>
```

for example

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Also add the following configuration in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
# the path you want your virtual environments to be saved and loaded from
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/<project_folder>

# most important, this is the program which loads virtualenv
# please update the path where virtualenvwrapper.sh is located
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Don't Forget to restart the shell.. or reload the configuration...

To test whether it worked

```
mkvirtualenv test
```

if you see a test environment created then everything is ok.

For Detailed Installation Instructions go to the docs: [virtualenvwrapper installation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Answer (score 7):

For me it was:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I changed the line to:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

It worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

This error means - program `virtualenv` is not in your system path. This mostly happens if you install `virtualenv` via pip without sudo. This kind of installation stores data in users local directory `e.g ~/.local/bin`. So first step is to find where this binary present. You can do that using `locate` program. First update its database using `sudo updatedb`. Then run `locate *bin/virtualenv`. Whatever path you get, append it in system path variable. This you can do by adding below line in your shell config file e.g. `~/.bashrc or ~/.zshenv`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/path
```

e.g.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Now open new shell and try again. Error should be gone.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I tested use this command:

```
 sudo find / -name "virtualenv"
```

and I have a list with all path to this file,

I tested one to one   and solved with path:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

My configurations to environment variables is :

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/bin/virtualenv
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

in file `.bashrc.`
Now all its works.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it was (using zsh) in this way:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH`

I simply located the file of virtualenvwrapper.sh inside this path `/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH`

and added that path to PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I have set the variable `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` in my **.zshrc** to the full path of the `virtualenv` binary and it works for me.

Here is my **.zshrc** file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv
source $HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PYTHONPATH makes me think you have Homebrew installed. It sounds like virtualenvwrapper was installed with either your system pip or your homebrew pip while it is being executed with the opposite python interpreter.

Comment: That's right, homebrew is installed. It seems like it is installed with both, could it cause a problem? I though that the interpreter crawls my PYTHONPATH and use the first virtualenv he finds.

Comment: I don't use virtualenvwrapper but it seems the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script that is `source`d determines which python interpreter to use before exporting the wrapper functions to your current environment.

Comment: You mean the virtualenvwrapper.sh ?

Comment: I did, sorry. I clarified the above comment.

Comment: Ah, this script's purpose is to define some functions in bash, such as "workon". You have its source here : https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/99610611439144487f1876927fbfe90dc40d3b78/virtualenvwrapper.sh?at=master

Comment: Ah, therefore, perhaps should I search in my PATH and not in my PYTHONPATH if virtualenvwrapper isn't written in python but in BASH...? I'll check this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issues and tried many many things, what found as a solution is i had three pip version, pip with 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7. and 3.6 was the one works fine for many things, and install as `sudo pip3.6  install virtualenv`, and it works fine.
I would suggest, check your pip version and tried to install based on your pip ver.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all virtualenv related packages would work.

```
pip freeze -l | grep ^virtualenv | awk -F= '{print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows and I had the exact same problem. I had the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` environment variable in my `.bashrc` pointing to virtualenv, but I kept getting an error. Apparently, I was pointing to the virtualenv/ folder, instead of the virtualenv.exe executable file (which was in another location). Once I corrected it, everything worked for me.