# Can't find virtualenv in path even though its there

Tags: python, django, bash

I'm trying to set up Django. I have Python 3.6 installed, and I installed virtualenvwrapper using pip3.

Here is what my bash profile looks like:

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv"

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Every time I run

```
$ mkvirtualenv my_django_env
```

I get

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path
```

Comment: did u restart bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274642/error-virtualenvwrapper-could-not-find-virtualenv-in-your-path)

Comment: @KevinL. Yes, I did

Comment: Did you install virtualenv?

Comment: I doubt very much that "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv" should be on your PATH. That env var should contain directories to search, not binaries themselves; you should have the .../3.6/bin directory there, which will then be searched for the virtualenv file. (Assuming it is actually in that directory.)

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer should have been posted here as it is more relevant to this question.

I cannot tell you how stable solution this is going to be for others. What worked for me is adding **[Lazy Loading](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#lazy-loading)** which is described as an alternative initialization script. The error I was getting is that

*`mkvirtualenv` is not in your `PATH`*

when I tried to fire up a virtual env. Adding below script to my `.zshrc` file helped.

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`

Please also check [this](https://swapps.com/blog/how-to-configure-virtualenvwrapper-with-python3-in-osx-mojave/) out for the whole process of installing and creating virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper pacakages.